# No action was found on the controller 'Foo' that matches the request

Tags: c#, android, .net, asp.net-web-api2

I couldn't call web api with params from android. I can do without params so problem probably how I send params or how I get them.

Following code gives this error :

> No action was found on the controller 'Foo' that matches the request.

**Android**

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", session.getAccessToken())); 

json = restClientService.getResponseAsJSON("http://192.168.2.242/WebApi/api/fbfeed/foo/", params);
```

--

```
private HttpResponse getWebServiceResponse(String URL,
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> params) {
    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
    try {
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        }
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

**Config**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "UserCreateApi", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}", defaults: new { action = "Foo" });
```

**Controller**

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
public IHttpActionResult Foo([FromBody]string token)
{
     //some code
}
```

Comment: Instead of using AcceptVerbs, have you tried just doing [HttpGet, HttpPost] ?

Answer (score 0):

Is your controller inheriting from ApiController?  Can you hit the url from a browser on your local machine?